# export 'IDropdownRef' (reexported as 'IDropdownRef') was not found in './components/Dropdown/model' (module has no exports)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am getting below error while compiling in React: It shows a cross button on top-right. After clicking on it, I am able to proceed.

Compiled with problems:

```bash
X  ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-element-dropdown/lib/module/index.js 5:0-62  export '**IDropdownRef**' (reexported as 'IDropdownRef') was not found in '**./components/Dropdown/model**' (module has no exports)
```

How to remove this error?